# Equation of a parabola in 3D space

Tags: geometry, equation

I have two points with coordinates A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2). There is a third point which is vertex(lowest point) of the parabola. I only know z-coordinate of this point.
I need to find coordinates of the points that lie on a parabola that passes through these 3 points.
I am interested in coordinates that lie in between A and B.

Comment: This question appears to belong on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think you need to know more info like all the coordinates of the third point or more info about the parabola (constants or plane,...) or your task is to create any parabola that satisfy your input data (not just the one)?

Comment: A and B are top coordinates of the vertical lines. That is A is top coordinate of a vertical line and similarly B is a top coordinate of another vertical line. Vertical here means a line parallel to z axis i.e. going through xy plane. So basically my plane in which parabola lies, is fixed, which is a plane passing through these lines. I know the equation of the plane in which parabola lies,two points on parabola, and z coordinate of the vertex. Can i find equation(i think parametric equation is easier since i am interested in finding points between A and B that lie on this parabola)?

Comment: so your parabola is in plane parallel to XY ... you know the Z coordinate of it and know the A,B so it is really a 2D problem not 3D then. you should draw an image of your problem configuration because from your text I got the impression you have A,B as upper `endpoints` of parabola so you need more info to aquire the correct parabola or you can use any parabola going through A,B ??? also what lines ? if yu have 2 arbitrary points how to get the lines? are they perpendicular to each other and axis aligned perhaps??? btw if you want a  respond then add `@nick` to start of comment to notify user

Comment: @nick...so let me reframe my question.. I have 3 points A B C...i know (x,y,z) coordinates of A B and C. Can i find a parabola passing through them? what is parametric equation of a parabola curve in 3d?(not paraboloid)...

Comment: I think i can do the problem in 2D and then rotate the original (xyz) system into new (x'y'z') system..something like that?